# Different output each time I am running the code

Tags: python

Following is my code:

```py
import math
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Input
c = 1500
rho= 1000
S= 0.07
mu =0.001
R0 =0.00001
PA=5
ω =100000
PO=1 
PGO=1
Pa=1
A= (ω*R0/c)
B=Pa*(10**5)/(rho*(ω**2)*(R0**2))
C=(2*S)/(rho*(ω**2)*(R0**3))
D=(4*mu)/(rho*ω*(R0**2))
          
#Model Definition
def f(X, T):
    β = X[0]
    z = X[1]
    dβdT = z
    dzdT = (1/(β-(A*β*z)+(A*D)))*((-1.5*z**2)+(0.5*A*z**3)+(B*PGO/(β**3))-(C/β)-(D*z/β)-(B*PO)+(B*PA*math.sin(T))+
                              (A*B*PGO*z/(β**3))-(A*C*z/β)-(A*D*(z**2)/β)-(A*B*PO*z)+(A*B*PA*z*math.sin(T))-
                              (3*A*B*PGO*z/(β**3))+(A*C*z/β)+(A*D*(z**2)/β)+(A*B*PA*β*math.cos(T)))
    return [dβdT, dzdT]

#Initial Boundary Condition
X0 = [1, 0]

#Time Interval
T = np.linspace(0, 14, 250)

sol = odeint(f, X0, T)
β = sol[:,0]
z = sol[:,1]

t= (T/ω)*(10**6)   #micro seconds
R= β*R0*(10**6)    #micro meters
V= z*R0*ω

plt.plot(t,R)
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.legend('R')
```

**Output 1:**

[image: Output-1]

**Output 2:**

[image: Output-2]

**Output 3:**

[image: Output-3]

I am running the following code in Anaconda Spyder, but each time the output graph is different and each time the graph is the same up to 60 microseconds in the x axis. After this point, the output of the graph is different is each run. The expected outcome is a repeating curve every time as up to 60 microseconds.

Comment: Do you already test the `odeint` function for simple problem with known solution to test it whether the result is reproducible?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Does the code return any warning when you run it?

Comment: I get `Output 1` each time I run your code.

Comment: Hi Dudung!
I already tested it with other functions and its working fine. In this code also if you change the value of R0 to 0.0005 then also same output. I think there should be some problem related to stability of equation.

Comment: Hi Talha Tayyab!
What does Output 1 mean??
I am getting different plotted graph each time or sometimes after 2-3 attempts

Comment: Note that the formatting was a bit confusing and possibly misleading. I edited it to make it more clear. Anyway, obviously (IMHO) the first plot is "output 1".

Comment: @user20838423, instead of replying in comments, it's better to [edit] your question to clarify it (i.e. add the statement that you do not get any warnings). Comments are not meant to be kept forever, while the question is supposed to be still understandable in the future.